# Multiple Retrofit RestAdapters

Tags: java, retrofit, okhttp

I have a number of endpoints and have to have different `ErrorHandler`s & `RequestInterceptor`s for a few of them. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250503/2073248) answer [JakeWharton](https://github.com/JakeWharton) (one of the devs of `Retrofit`) says that `RestAdapter` should be treated as a singleton. In the same post another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512203/2073248) says a map of singletons is used to achieve endpoint specific `RequestInterceptors`.

To make sure that all the `RestAdapters` use the same connection pool when using `OkHttp`, I am sharing my `OkHttpClient`s among all the adapters like this

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
okHttpClient.setReadTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

OkClient okClient = new OkClient(okHttpClient);

RestAdapter restAdapter1 = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setClient(okClient)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setEndpoint("http://example.com/)
        .setErrorHandler(ErrHandlerFactory.get(Endpoint1.class))
        .setRequestInterceptor(ReqInterceptorFactory.get(Endpoint1.class))
        .build();

RestAdapter restAdapter2 = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setClient(okClient)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setEndpoint("http://example.com/)
        .setErrorHandler(ErrHandlerFactory.get(Endpoint2.class))
        .setRequestInterceptor(ReqInterceptorFactory.get(Endpoint2.class))
        .build();
```

where `Endpoint1` & `Endpoint2` are the `interface`s that follow Retrofit's annotations. The build RestAdapters are then used for further api calls. Is this the best way to have endpoint specific operations or am I missing something?